# redirect in formik with yup react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I'm playing around with formik and yup in react and I was wondering what is the best way to go about doing a redirect after a successful request?

I tried passing in the history object but it gave me an error saying that it was global:

```
const SignUp = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues({
    username,
    email,
    password,
    passwordConfirm,
    registerUser
  }) {
    return {
      username: username || '',
      email: email || '',
      password: password || '',
      passwordConfirm: passwordConfirm || ''
    };
  },

  validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    username: Yup.string()
      .required('must have username')
      .min(5, 'username must be 5 characters long'),
    email: Yup.string()
      .email('Please enter a valid email')
      .required('Email is required'),
    password: Yup.string().required('No password provided.'),
    passwordConfirmation: Yup.string().oneOf(
      [Yup.ref('password'), null],
      'Passwords must match'
    )
  }),

  handleSubmit(values, { resetForm }) {
    const user = {
      username: values.username,
      email: values.email,
      password: values.password
    };
    //registerUser(user)
    //re direct here ?
    resetForm();
  }
})(SignUpPage);

export default SignUp;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using **React Router**, and this is one of the route then you will have `history` in props.

I've created a small example, check it out.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-formik-form-validation-gge2u7?file=App%2FApp.jsx

Answer (score 2):

```js
window.location.replace('/homepage');
```

use this one in `handleSubmit` .

Comment: There is something weird about using NextJs internal routing functions when submitting Formik. I kept getting `TypeError: e.slice is not a function` after submitting a form using something like `router.push('/myredirectPath')`, which would route in the browser address bar but show the error coming from the form page. If I refreshed the browser page the error would disappear and show me the content of the `/myredirectPath`. The `window.location.replace` function was the only thing that seemed to prevent the error.